# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Service configuration not found... Parameter name: ITestService

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

i am trying to execute a test case method through HTTP post method , there i am getting the above exception when it is calling the ItestService.which is a WCF service contract.

Comment: Um, [mcve] please. At least provide the full exception and some code.

Comment: The name of the service the implemented class of the service interface (Namespace.ServiceClass), the contract of the service is the service interface(Namespace.IService)